# Core Data only saving one attribute while working with 2 entities

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a view where I want to save the attribute values of 2 entities: root beer and comments. These values have an inverse relationship but for some reason, only the rating value is being saved. Can someone tell me what, if anything, I'm doing wrong; or, should be doing differently?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Comments* com = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Comments" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    RootBeer* rootBeer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RootBeer" inManagedObjectContext:context];

//save root beer values
[rootBeer setValue:self.rootBeerNameField.text forKey:@"rootBeerName"];
[rootBeer setValue:self.rootBeerBrewerField.text forKey:@"rootBeerBrewer"];
[rootBeer setValue:self.rootBeerLocationField.text forKey:@"rootBeerLocation"];
[rootBeer setValue:self.rootBeerDetailField.text forKey:@"rootBeerDetails"];

//save root beer comments/notes
[com setValue:self.rootBeerNotes.text forKey:@"rootBeerComment"];
[rootBeer setValue:com forKey:@"comments"];
//This is the only value that is being stored
[rootBeer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:rateView.rate]forKey:@"myRootBeerRating"];

NSError* error = nil;
if(![context save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}


NSLog(@"Saved!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the debugger while stepping through this method. My guess is that you haven't connected your properties to the text fields properly, or the text values are nil at that point. It seems too much of a coincidence that the one input view you access directly rather than through a property (rateView) is the only one that works.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I should have thought of this sooner. As soon as I stepped in, I realized that I didn't attach my text fields. I feel like an idiot. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @jrturton ..haha, superb mate nice observation,

Answer (score 1):

I assume comments have one to one and rootbeer has one to many relationship.

You don't need to set the both sides of relationship. You need to set only one side and core data would set the other side for you.

```
//save root beer comments/notes
[com setValue:self.rootBeerNotes.text forKey:@"rootBeerComment"];

//No need for this
//[rootBeer setValue:com forKey:@"comments"];
```

Instead set

```
//Set the one to one of rootBeer to comment 
[com setValue:rootBeer forKey:@"key for root beer"];
```

Comment: This is a good point, its always easier to set a relationship from the "one" side, otherwise you have to use the `addCommentsObject` generated accessor.